# How to skip woocommerce checkout out page?

Tags: plugins

I use woocommerce plugin for my shop. I want to skip the checkout page where users give shipping details. So the system will be when they select a product and after go to the cart page they will go to paypal and from paypal we will get the adress. Any idea how i can build this, Please help me. I am newbie.

Comment: Basically I don't want to redirect the user in the checkout page, so in the cart page when the click on the "Proceed to to Checkout" then they will directly go to the paypal. Would you please let me know how i can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is an option in the Woocommerce to not include shipping

Go to Woocommerce > Settings> Shipping

and disable the options there

[image: Woocommerce Settings]

Comment: thanks for your answer, Basically I don't want to redirect the user in the checkout page, so in the cart page when the click on the "Proceed to to Checkout" then they will directly go to the paypal. Would you please let me know how i can do that?

Comment: Basically I don't want to redirect the user in the checkout page, so in the cart page when the click on the "Proceed to to Checkout" then they will directly go to the paypal. Would you please let me know how i can do that?

Comment: Hi Jewel  this should be asked as a new question ... but in answer to this ... go to WooCommerce > General and CHECK Allow Guest to Checkout.   You should also have a look at the documents at http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/user-guide/extensions/paypal-express-checkout/

Answer (score 2):

To skip the checkout page you can redirect the add to cart URL to the checkout URL. Be careful as the following as no conditional logic and so applies to *any* product added.

```
function wpa_59232_redirect_to_checkout( $url ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    // Remove default cart message
    $woocommerce->clear_messages();

    // Redirect to checkout
    $url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();

    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'add_to_cart_redirect', 'wpa_59232_redirect_to_checkout' );
```